# How to use Parsec to separate a string by a specific string

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am learning parsec, and just encountered the following situation. I want to separate a `String` into `[String]` by a specific `String`; for example, I get `"abcSEPdef` , and the separator is "SEP", so, after being parsed, I should get a `["abc","def"]`

I believe the parser should look like `sepBy a_parser (string "SEP")`; however, I don't know how the `a_parser` should be like.

Comment: If *all* you want to do is separate a string that way, it's probably easier to use the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package. But it's likely that's not all you want to do -- e.g. the pieces between `SEP` probably have some structure of their own. And then we can't help you write a parser for that structure, because you haven't told us what it is!

Comment: No, the purpose of trying to seperate string is to learn parsec library...

Comment: @duplode, as I want to seperate the string  by "SEP", I think the parser `a_parser` should at least succeeds only when the string contains no "SEP" inside

Comment: You are right. I have removed the misleading comment (which I wrote way too quickly).

Comment: @DanielWagner, I finally realized that I could incorporate [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html) into parsec by `mysep sep = getInput >>= return . DLS.splitOn sep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `manyTill` a few times will work:

```
uptoSEP = manyTill anyChar (eof <|> (string "SEP" >> return ()))

splitSEP = manyTill uptoSEP eof
```

E.g.:

```
ghci> parseTest splitSEP "abcSEPdefSEPxyz"
["abc","def","xyz"]
```

You'll want to enable the `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` pragma.

Answer (score 1):

Find a negation of "SEP", and let that parser be parseNonSEP.
It is theoretically ensured that there parseNonSEP falls under the category of a regular language, because regular languages are closed under negation, and there should be a straigforward way to implement this.

Then,

sepBy pareseNonSEP (string "SEP")

will do the job.

Well, what I mentioned above is a rather theoretical approach :)
More parsec-style way may be to look ahead the list of input tokens without actually consuming the input and/or use backtracking such as try, notFollowedBy, lookAhead.

See

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a way to incorporate `split` package into `parsec`:

```
module Sep where
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import qualified Data.List.Split  as DLS
mysep :: String -> Parser [String]
mysep sep = getInput >>= return . DLS.splitOn sep
```

Answer (score 0):

The [replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
package has a
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap) combinator for splitting strings and capturing the separation.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec

parseTest (sepCap (chunk "SEP" :: Parsec Void String String)) "abcSEPdef"
```

```hs
[Left "abc",Right "SEP",Left "def"]
```